# Jquery selector not working in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I used Jquery to select two elements and hide them with their attributes by the following:

```
$('input[name=login]').hide();

$('span[class=forgot]').hide();
```

Both lines properly selects the desired elements and hide them well in FF and IE. However in chrome, the selector is not picking up the object. Anything I should do differently?

Comment: Nope. It wouldn't even matter what version of Chrome, this particular code would not have any issues. But just to be clear, It's probably best to do `$('input[name="login"]')`

Comment: Code looks ok... my guess your problem is somewhere else. Chrome is known for interpreting js much faster than other browsers so... are you sure your elements are loaded when that code is run?

Comment: Your code works fine in Chrome (http://jsfiddle.net/kcyLr/1/); your problem must lie elsewhere. Perhaps consider providing a small, complete example that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You should use:

```
 $('input[name="login"]').hide();

 $('span[class="forgot"]').hide();
```

(note the additional quotes)

Comment: it's only usefull if string to search contains some space characters

Answer (score 2):

It may be that you're missing quotes:

```
$('input[name="login"]').hide();
```

Also, for classes, you might as well use the native selector:

```
$('span.forgot').hide();
```

Comment: The point about classes kind of depends; if you only wanted to select the element when it **only** had the class `forgot` (and had no other classes), then `span.forgot` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For the span selector, you can use:

```
$('span.forgot').hide();
```

As for the input, you can use:

```
$('input[name="login"]').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

look  for console errors in developer tool.

you can try with

```
jQuery('input[name=login]').hide();

jquery('span[class=forgot]').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("input[name='login']").hide();    
 $('span.forgot').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, turns out there is some issue with me referencing the Jquery library.

I do not know what is the reason, but referencing the library does not seem to be working.

After I copy pasted the entire Jquery Js file into the code. Everything works.

Again Thanks all for your help.